# Is there a way to enable a log file to spawn-fcgi and fcgiwrap?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, bugzilla, spawn-fcgi

I'm trying to setup Bugzilla.  I'm getting a 403 error.  There are no error messages in the nginx error log file. I'm pretty sure that the 403 message is being sent from upstream.  I say that because I can create a 403 error in the nginx error log by messing with the security of the index.cgi file.   Right now, I'm getting nothing in the log. I suspect that the problem is some kind of access denied problem with spawn-fcgi or fcgiwrap.

**Is there a way to adjust the settings to spawn-fcgi or fcgiwrap so that it generates log file entries?**

Here is how I have the service configured.

```
# more /etc/sysconfig/spawn-fcgi
FCGI_SOCKET=/var/run/fcgiwrap.sock
FCGI_PROGRAM=/usr/local/sbin/fcgiwrap
FCGI_USER=nginx
FCGI_GROUP=nginx
FCGI_EXTRA_OPTIONS="-M 0700"
OPTIONS="-u $FCGI_USER -g $FCGI_GROUP -s $FCGI_SOCKET -S $FCGI_EXTRA_OPTIONS -
F 1 -P /var/run/spawn-fcgi.pid -- $FCGI_PROGRAM"
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I had to append `-f` to the end of this line.  This will redirect the errors to the stderr and then the nginx error log will show it.

**OPTIONS="-u $FCGI_USER -g $FCGI_GROUP -s $FCGI_SOCKET -S $FCGI_EXTRA_OPTIONS -
F 1 -P /var/run/spawn-fcgi.pid -- $FCGI_PROGRAM -f"**

Comment: The `-f` flag also solved an issue where git-http-backend errors were not registering in the nginx logs.